# Problem Adding TypeScript to existing ReactNative Project

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

So, I've recently decided that it would be best for me to use TypeScript in some parts of my ReactNative project, and I searched through the internet to see if it was possible and I found out that yes.

[I followed carefully "Adding TypeScript to an Existing Project" of the ReactNative documentation in](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript#what-does-react-native--typescript-look-like)   *except* for the 3rd item, which is 'Rename a JavaScript file to be *.tsx' because I didn't understand it and got scared.

But the thing is, I started a screen file in TypeScript but I get ridiculous errors that make no sense to me. For example:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const HomeAq = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>HomeAq</Text>
  )
    </View>
}

export default HomeAq

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

When I run `npx tsc` to check it, I get:

```
src/Screens/HomeAq.ts:7:21 - error TS1161: Unterminated regular expression literal.

7       <Text>HomeAq</Text>
  

src/Screens/HomeAq.ts:8:7 - error TS1161: Unterminated regular expression literal.

8     </View>
        


Found 2 errors in the same file, starting at: src/Screens/HomeAq.ts:7
```

My tsconfig.json file seems to be acceptable:

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
}
```

I've tried running the install command again, reloading VSCode a million times, checked the tsconfig file multiple times, created hundreds of new TypeScript files, I even checked node_modules to see if something abnormal was happening there, but nothing. Please help

Comment: did you installed typescript @types/react @types/react-native ?

Answer (score 0):

When using TypeScript, any file having JSX code needs to have `.tsx` extension. `.ts` will not work, which is what you seem to be using from your error messages. Rename all files with JSX code inside to `.tsx` should fix the errors you are getting.